# How to read the application data of a Minidump with full Application data for a Visual C++ application?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, dump, crash-dumps

I have a application which has been gone into hang state. this application is really a combination of three different exes. UI.exe, core.exe, core.dll. all of these are basically built on VC++. so when i look into the application logs i can see ui.exe is stopped somewhere. So I have taken the Mini dump with full application data via Task Manager->processes->select the ui.exe and core.exe right click it and "Create dump file". I have some 150MB + data present in the ui.exe dmp file. how to analyze it?

So far I can able to load the dump file with all its necessary pdb files (application + System) and successfully loaded the values. I can able to see the application is running but not responding to the core.exe request.

Now I really looking for the application data which is in heap and stack of the ui.exe and core.exe with that i can able to check where the data is getting piled up. what variable / array is eating up the value. can any one tel me a way for this?

Comment: A `dll` isn't an `executable`. Please show your research- what code have you tried? What research have you done?

Comment: yes agreed for the dll. dll is loaded into that core.exe, this is a very vast application code we dont know where it is hitting into hung state. we try to read out the application memory so that we can understand which variables are occupied more memory. we can see the application is running without any response for more hours (but not consistent).

Comment: Is there any way to look int the stack memory except the stall callback reference and the heap memory in the dump file?

Comment: I take it that you have the full source code and don't know where it's hanging? I'd suggest you run your program with a debugger...

Comment: yes you are right, i have the full source code but the problem is, issue happening with some set of PCs (not with all) where i cannot able to put the source code and run. i have added as far as logs but nothing helps.

Comment: If you managed to load dump file in the debugger, .pdb are loaded and source files are available, you can open Threads window, and see where every thread is executed. To see variable values, use debugger by the same way, as in standard debugging. In every thread you can see local variables, global variables, class members etc. Of course, debugging Release version has some difficulties because of compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options, depending on the type of hang you experience. One is a low CPU hang, which could be a deadlock. The other is a high CPU hang, which could be an endless loop. Debugging a deadlock is typically easier, since you get good and always the same callstacks. Debugging a high CPU hang is harder, because there may be different callstacks, depending on the time when you took the dump. You'll need several dumps - or better use a profiler.

To answer your questions:

**How to analyze it?**

There are three main choices

- Visual Studio. This seems what you have done, but for some reason you are not able to conclude something from the things you see. This might happen because Visual Studio does not offer the necessary analysis steps or they are hidden somewhere so you didn't find them.
- [WinDbg](http://www.microsoft.com/click/services/Redirect2.ashx?CR_EAC=300135395) certainly is the choice for all guys who want more commands and more control. Download it now, start using it for simple cases, get familiar with it and finally you will hate it but still it's your favorite debugger. Since it is ridiculously hard to learn you won't make good progress for this case. If you go for it, use `!analyze -v` as your first command. But in any case try
- [DebugDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42933). Do a hang analysis and hopefully it will give you some useful information.

**Can any one tell me a way for this? [finding out where the data is getting piled up]**

I cannot clearly see how a big amount of data is related to a hung application. The data is on the stack or on the heap, depending on how you implemented your application. Note that in C++ there is no clear mapping between object types and memory as there is in .NET. You cannot simply type a command like *Show me all objects of type Xyz*.

In Visual Studio you could be lucky for local variables etc., since they might be resolved. In WinDbg you'd use some of the `!heap` commands and probably configure some [GFlag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) settings to keep track of memory allocations.